# Custom object class not persisting with ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, nullreferenceexception, viewstate

I have a private, Serializable custom object class called **results** within my namespace which I use to store the results of a file upload/server push:

```
namespace DataUploadTool
{
enum errors {none, format, data, type, unk};

public partial class uploader : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private results res;

    [Serializable]
    private class results
    {
        public string errLogPath { get; set; }
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        public int errorType { get; set; }
        public int rowsImported { get; set; }
        public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
    }

    ...
}
```

I set the members of the object in the standard way in my code, i.e.
`res.fileName = fileUpload.FileName;` etc.

I add the object to the ViewState:

```
void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState.Add("resultsLog", res);
    }
```

And I **attempt** to retrieve it like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        res = new results();

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (ViewState["resultsLog"] != null)
            {
                results test;
                test = (results)ViewState["resultslog"];
                error.Text = test.rowsImported.ToString();
            }
            else // Do things
        }
    }
```

The problem is I keep getting nullReferenceException on the line `error.Text = test.rowsImported.ToString();`.

The built in data visulaizer tool in Visual Studio tells me that **test** is null after the line where it is retrieved from the ViewState, which doesn't make any sense at all because it was determined not null by the if statement! I am at a complete loss on how or why this is happening.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong.

The PostBack occurs before the ViewState save because my database populating function was called before that.

If you're having the problem where your ViewState/Session variable is null the **first postback** but proceeding postbacks contain the variable from the **previous request**, that is what is happening.

Clarification: Let's say after every database insertion (occuring on the button_onClick function) I want to display the result of the inserting in a label. The following actions in order exemplify this:

1. Select **valid** file with data to upload -> click upload -> postback occurs and ViewState/Session variable is **null**
2. Select **invalid** file to upload -> click upload -> postback occurs and ViewState/Session variable reads **true**
3. Select **valid** file to upload -> click upload -> postback occurs and ViewState/Session variable reads **false**

So as you see the updated variable is visible to the **following** postback.

Essentially, I didn't need to use ViewState or Session at all. I could operate on the object data at the end of the onClick function because at that point the postback had already occurred.

**TL;DR:**
If you're having problems with ViewState or Session variables/objects not persisting, or are experiencing odd "one-off" logic errors, then add breakpoints at each line of code involving:

```
- View/Session state setting/getting
- Function declarations which call these getters/setters
- Any function which accesses database data (reading/writing)
```

By following these breadcrumbs, you'll very quickly recognize the order in which the page life cycle is progressing.